# DrRacket Deleting Root of A Binary Search Tree

Tags: scheme, racket, binary-search-tree

PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS IS HOMEWORK! --> I am not looking for direct code examples, but rather some gentle massaging of my reasoning...

I have been asked to write a function that removes the root of a binary search tree by doing three things:
i) rotating the tree to the right
ii) removing the root of the right subtree (Which was the original bst root)
iii) rebuilding the bst with the new root (which was the left of the original tree) and the appropriate rearrangements of the children of that node... Here's what I have:

```
    (define (rm-root my-bst)
      (list (key (rot-r my-bst)) 
            (left (rot-r my-bst)) 
            (append (right (right (rot-r my-bst))) 
                    (left (right (rot-r my-bst))))))
```

Which is all great, expect for that it doesn't rebuild the tree with the children of the node that was "promoted" to the root node. Can anyone help me think about how I should go about implementing that? I should mention that we have defined Bst's as lists and that the function rot-r rotates the bst to the right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure this will be useful 12 days after the question was asked, but here goes.

To be clear, I'm guessing that the data structure is of the form (list key left right), where left and right are also trees (or empty, but that's irrelevant to this). If this is not the case, clarification of that would be needed.

One problem in your code is that you do not want to directly append the two lists you have together for the right. You want to make a list with the key of one of those, and then the left and right. If I am reading this correctly, the left function should return a tree and therefore should work fine.

I would check the implementation of rot-r if I were you as that seems to be the main possibility for things going wrong.